# Why do journals require authors to provide funding information?

Tags: funding, paper-submission, open-access

Recently I have communicated a manuscript to Springer journal. In editorial system I was required to furnish funding information. If the funding information is available then does that mean that I have to publish my work through open access by paying fee from funds that have been sanctioned  to me?

Although the journal is not open access journal but I am afraid if they ask for article processing fee after acceptance of manuscript. My sanctioned funds does not cover article processing charges

Comment: Are you talking about "_Our submission systems will **offer the option** to include your funding source in a standardized way._" from the [Springer web page](https://www.springer.com/gp/authors-editors/journal-author/journal-author-helpdesk/submission/1302)?

Comment: I don't know if this is the reason in your case, but many journals require disclosing the funding source as a way of managing perceived or real conflicts of interest. This is especially important in medical studies, which are often funded by pharmaceutical companies. Here's [an example](http://www.thelancet.com/lancet/information-for-authors/statements-permissions-signatures).

Comment: Do you wish to pay for open access? If not, nobody can force you to. Acknowledging and disclosing funding is standard for academic articles.

Comment: Your situation is a bit too vague, does your funding source *require* you to pay for open access (which I think is pretty stupid, but I know it exists) and you would prefer not to but are afraid that disclosing that funding will reveal that you do not abide by their policy? If that is the case, the journal doesn't care, it's between you and your funding agency.

Comment: @CapeCode : My sanctioned funding does not cover APC. I have furnished them(Springer) my funding source.

Comment: *I am afraid if they ask for open access fee after acceptance of manuscript* Does this journal require APC payment for all submissions? If yes, then you will have to pay regardless of your funding. If not then it's unclear why you're worried.

Comment: @CapeCode, actually some funding agencies now mandate open access. The [Wikipeida](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_access#Policies_and_mandates) page talk about the mandates more.

Comment: @RichardErickson having a self-archiving mandate is not the same as forcing authors to pay for gold OA.

Comment: @CapeCode, I agree self-archiving is different than paying for gold OA. However, funding sources can require a great deal as a condition of the PI accepting funding. Some funding agencies seem to be moving towards requiring open access. For example, the [Welcome Trust](https://wellcome.ac.uk/funding/managing-grant/open-access-policy) _"encourage – and where it pays an open access fee, require – authors and publishers to licence research papers using the Creative Commons Attribution licence"_. In the future, funding bodies such as this may require all research they fund to be open access.

Comment: @RichardErickson I understand that. In my second comment above I asked OP if that was a requirement from the funding body. As a side note, I think it's sad that funding agencies encourage such a bad practice. But at least it's their own money they're throwing out the window.

Answer (score 9):

Funding information is often required even when a journal has no open source option to it. The source of funding is a major potential conflict of interest, and as such is a key piece of information in evaluating a paper.

That being said, it may also be used to determine things like whether or not they should give a break on open access fees, whether it needs to be deposited in Pubmed Central, etc.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Fomite's answer, there is another reason to demand funding information: to ensure that any possible conflicts of interest in the research that arise because of funding are disclosed. This is particularly an issue in medical research, where many studies are funded by industry.